# Applying a function to chunks of the Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, resampling

I have a `Dataframe (df)` (for instance - simplified version)

```
              A    B 
 0           2.0   3.0
 1           3.0   4.0
```

and generated 20 bootstrap resamples that are all now in the same df but differ in the *Resample Nr.*

```
                                A    B 
   
0     1             0           2.0   3.0
1     1             1           3.0   4.0
2     2             1           3.0   4.0
3     2             1           3.0   4.0
..    ..
..    .. 
39    20            0           2.0    3.0
40    20            0           2.0    3.0
```

Now I want to apply a certain function on each *Reample Nr*. Say:

```
C = sum(df['A'] * df['B']) / sum(df['B'] ** 2)
```

The outlook would look like this:

```
                                 A    B           C
0     1             0           2.0   3.0   Calculated Value X1
1     1             1           3.0   4.0   Calculated Value X1
2     2             1           3.0   4.0   Calculated Value X2
3     2             1           3.0   4.0   Calculated Value X2
..    ..
..    .. 
39    20            0           2.0    3.0  Calculated Value  X20
40    20            0           2.0    3.0  Calculated Value  X20
```

So there are 20 different new values.

I know there is a df.iloc command where I can specify my row selection `df.iloc[row, column]` but I would like to find a command where I don't have to repeat the code for the 20 samples.
My goal is to find a command that identifies the *Resample Nr.* automatically and then calculates the function for each *Resample Nr.*

How can I do this?

Thank you!

Comment: Please correct the formula, i think you are missing a paranthesis.. Also if possible include the expected output for the given sample.

Comment: So the formula is `sum(df['A'] * df['B']) / sum(df['A'] ** 2)`, right?

Comment: ```sum(df['A'] * df['B']) / sum(df['B'] ** 2``` (edited). But yes, exactly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.assign`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) to create two new columns `x` and `y` that corresponds to `df['A'] * df['B']` and `df['B']**2`, then use [`DataFrame.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) on `Resample Nr.` (or `level=1`) and `transform` using `sum`:

```
s = df.assign(x=df['A'].mul(df['B']), y=df['B']**2)\
      .groupby(level=1)[['x', 'y']].transform('sum')
df['C'] = s['x'].div(s['y'])
```

Result:

```
           A    B         C
0  1  0  2.0  3.0  0.720000
1  1  1  3.0  4.0  0.720000
2  2  1  3.0  4.0  0.750000
3  2  1  3.0  4.0  0.750000
39 20 0  2.0  3.0  0.666667
40 20 0  2.0  3.0  0.666667
```